# Hello world app code is not working

Tags: java, println

Hi I am making a hello world app, my third line is keep messing up and I don't know why.
Any suggestions, my teacher gave me a brief direction for it but looks like i messed up on something and i went through it three times.

```
public class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(“Hello World”);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us some code so that we could help?

Comment: `“` and `”` are not valid string delimiters. you need to use plain quotes, e.g. `shift`-`'` on your keyboard, not the fancy typographic "6's and 9's". e.g. use a real code editor, not something useless like MS Word

Comment: @Mingyu- I see some code!

Comment: Thank you, @dkroy - don't know what I was thinking!  There's no argc there!  ;-)

Comment: @MarcB not everyone is using qwerty keyboards :p Shift+' gives 4 here

Comment: thankyou @MarcB this helped me alot i just started learning java

Comment: @fge: hence the "e.g." - "for example"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote marks are not good.

Java standard quotes for strings **are** `"`, and **not** `”`.

Anyways, also try `System.out.println(1);` and tell us does it print number.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `"`  instead of `”` for your string...

```
public class HelloWorldApp {

 public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }

 }
```

Comment: Not really, single quotes are for chars.

Comment: Good edit, but now your answer is redundant.